# How to find a 6 element in chain in P(1,2,3,4)

Tags: order-theory

I am trying to find a chain with six elements as I am told it exists as it is the Dedekind number for the power set of $\{1,2,3,4\}$

But I keep only being able to come up with 5

for example

$\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

I cant add in another singleton because then it wont be able to be ordered with $\{1\}$ for same reason I cant add a two element one as it wont be ordered with $\{1,2\}$

If it helps to provide context, I am trying to find the minimum number k of chains it takes to write the partial order as a decomposition of said chains.

Also it appears no such chain exists. So where is the mistake in what I have previously said? I used the binomial formula on n choose floor(n/2) ie 4 choose 2 which is 6

Any advice /hints/help please?

Comment: clearly no such chain exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at wikipedia, the dedeking number is actually the number of elements in an antichain (not chain).

In the case in which your base set is just the powerset of $\{1,2,3,\dots n\}$ the dedekind number is known to be $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ by a beautiful theorem due to Sperner.

So in our case the Dedekind number is $\binom{4}{2}=6$.

The only antichain of this size is $\{ \{1,2\}, \{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$